# How to request for merging my 2 askubuntu accounts?

Tags: user-accounts, support

I accidentally created a second account because I had forgotten about my first account, but now I want to merge them and keep single account.

I want this account to be merged into https://askubuntu.com/users/109523/tobson

thanks

Comment: Please use the [contact us link](http://askubuntu.com/help) at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any posts associated with the other account. I can destroy the other account and you can continue to use the site with this account. Would you like that?

Comment: @Aditya You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Seth: Done :-)

Comment: I think I prefer the solution of jokerdino. So delete my old account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the **[Contact Us](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help)** link at the bottom of this page.

[image: contact-us]

In the link that opens up, click on **Merge user profiles** under **Account Management**.

[image: help-center]

If you have access to both the accounts (ie; you know the Login ID and Password), you can merge the accounts yourself by following the instructions on that page.

Otherwise, you may [fill out this form](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/other), to request the merger of the two accounts.

Comment: @Mods: This line *"If you have lost access to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form."* at the end of [this page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/user-merge) is redundant. And if there is some specific format to fill up [this form](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/other), I would request you to please edit the answer with same... :-)