# Not able to merge IDs

Tags: support, status-completed, merge

I'm not managing to merge my openid (140578) with this one I just registered in (141013).

Any idea pls?

Thx!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to request for merging my 2 askubuntu accounts?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6319/114818)

Comment: Are you trying to merge OpenIDs, or are you trying to merge Ask Ubuntu accounts, or are you trying to use more than one OpenID with a single Ubuntu account?

Answer (score 2):

Your accounts should now be merged.