# Wubi post a mess

Tags: discussion

So...I somehow marked my own post as solved, because I was responding to one of the suggested fixes.  It didn't work, so I was commenting on that fact.I guess I somehow was able to mark my post solved. I tried the auto suggestion and it didn't work, so I have the same problem ,but you fine folks think it's solved!If no one understands this, can you delete my posts and I'll try  my question  again?I'll be more careful next time! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Stich,

you appear to have at least four accounts that have been created:

- https://askubuntu.com/users/221865
- https://askubuntu.com/users/221885
- https://askubuntu.com/users/221961
- https://askubuntu.com/users/221970

If these are indeed your accounts, you can request yourself that these accounts are merged together.  Once done, you will then be able to edit any previous posts that you have created.

The instructions on how to merge accounts can be found in this link:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6319/how-to-request-for-merging-my-2-askubuntu-accounts

Its probably better and cleaner to go through this route -  it keeps the site tidier and gives others here better visibility of the progress of your question or questions.

If necessary, we can merge any posts together or close others that are indeed duplicates.

Comment: One of the reasons I wanted people to be registered to post questions.